# Can I install a rack if I install plugin mudguards?

Tags: rack, fenders

I bought a Cube Cross Pro https://www.cube.eu/2019/bikes/trekking/tour/cross/cube-cross-pro-bluenorange-2019/

I want to install a rack and mudguards. I found these nice plugin mudguards https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/sks-germany-x-blade-shockblade-dark-set-29-617315 .... however I'm not sure if I bought them I will be able to install a rack or not. Why? because the rear mudgaurds will probably take the entire space on back above the tire. Here is a rack I'm thinking to buy https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/cube-porter-heavy-duty-28-29-528212

So what do you think? I haven't done something like that before.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that will work. If you are going to install the mudguard between rack and tire the “arm” of the SKS X-Blade mudguard is likely to collide with the two stays of the rack. There is a chance that you are lucky and the spacing is just right to fit it through.

If you are going to install mudguards, why not get some proper ones like the SKS Bluemels?

As a sidenote: Why get such a heavy and ugly rack for such a nice and relatively light bike? Something like the Tubus Fly (Vega if you need more tire clearance) would fit much more nicely.

Comment: Another hack is to line the underside of the parcel rack with a piece of plastic.  If the plastic is ziptied underneath the rack it can still be used for parcels.  This acts as a half-mudguard and works well, but it doesn't protect the BB area.